# Прозрачность ElementHost

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Можно ли сделать экземпляр [`ElementHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) прозрачным? Перепробовал множество вариантов, но ни один не помог.

Comment: А что такое `ElementHost`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет. На стыке WinForms и WPF прозрачность не поддерживается.

Какое-то время назад разрабы Microsoft совершили героический подвиг и таки решили эту проблему, но эта фича не попала в релиз, потому что её сочли слишком костыльной. Такая боль.

Comment: Жаль. А есть хоть ссылки на гитхаб или что-то такое? Или где там были эти самые попытки?

Comment: @VladD Какой гитхаб? Исходники WPF закрыты же. В sourceof.net попадают только релизы, на гитхабе только игрушечный дотнет. Попытки совершались в недрах MS.

Comment: Я думал, они есть где-то [тут](https://github.com/dotnet). Вдвойне жаль.

Comment: @VladD На гитхабе только "дотнет для ASP.NET", единственная цель которого — отжать веб у красноглазых. "Подсистема линукса" в десятке — из той же серии. WPF, WinForms и прочее как были, так и остаются с частично "приоткрытыми" исходниками (даже на sourceof.net с ограничивающей лицензией далеко не всё выложено, WPF не скомпилить, например).